# context without channels in the same thread of execution

Tags: go, concurrency

Can't figure out how I can cancel a task if it takes to much to time compute in the same thread of execution via context semantics?

I use this example as a reference point
https://golang.org/src/context/context_test.go

The goal here call a doWork, if doWork takes to much time to compute, GetValueWithDeadline should after a timeout return 0, or if caller called cancel that cancel a wait, (here it main is caller) or the value returned in in give a time window.

The same scenario can be done In a different way. ( separate goroutine sleep, wakeup check value etc, condition on a mutex, etc) but I really want to understand the correct way to use context.

The channel semantic I understand but here I can't achieve the desired effect, the default case
call to a doWork fault under default case and sleep.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type Server struct {
    lock sync.Mutex
}

func NewServer() *Server {
    s := new(Server)
    return s
}

func (s *Server) doWork() int {
    s.lock.Lock()
    defer s.lock.Unlock()
    r := rand.Intn(100)
    log.Printf("Going to nap for %d", r)
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(r) * time.Millisecond)
    return r
}

// I take an example from here and it very unclear where is do work executed
// https://golang.org/src/context/context_test.go

func (s *Server)  GetValueWithDeadline(ctx context.Context) int {
    val := 0
    select {
        case <- time.After(150 * time.Millisecond):
                fmt.Println("overslept")
                return 0
        case <- ctx.Done():
                fmt.Println(ctx.Err())
                return 0
        default:
                val = s.doWork()
    }

    return all
}

func main() {

    rand.Seed(time.Now().UTC().UnixNano())
    s := NewServer()
    for i :=0; i < 10; i++ {
        d := time.Now().Add(50 * time.Millisecond)
        ctx, cancel := context.WithDeadline(context.Background(), d)
        log.Print(s.GetValueWithDeadline(ctx))
        cancel()
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your approach.

#### What problem contexts solve

First, the primary reason contexts were invented in Go is that they allow to unify an approach to *cancellation* of a set of tasks.

To explain this concept using a simple example, consider a client request to some sever; to simplify further let it be an HTTP request.
The client connects to the server, sends some data telling the server what to do to fulfill the request and then waits for the server to respond.
Let's now suppose the request requires elaborate and time-consuming processing on the server — for instance, suppose it needs to perform multiple complex queries to multiple remote database engines, do multiple HTTP requests to external services and then process the acquired results to actually produce the data the client wants.

So the client starts its request and the server goes on with all those requests.
To hide latency of individual tasks the server has to perform to fulfill the request, it runs them in separate goroutines.
Once each goroutine completes the assigned task, it communicates its result (and/or an error) back to the goroutine which handles the client's request, and so on.

Now suppose that the client fails to wait for the response to its request for whatever reason — a network outage, an explicit timeout in the client's software, the user kills the app which initiated the request etc, — there are lots of possibilities.

As you can see, there's little sense for the server to continue spending resources to finish the tasks which were logically bound to the now-dead request: there's no one to hear back the result anyway.
So it makes sense to reap those tasks once we know the request is not going to be completed, and that's where contexts come into play: you can associate each incoming request with a single context and then either pass it itself to any goroutine spawned to carry out a single task required to be done to fulfill the request, or derive another context from that and pass it instead.
Then, as soon as you *cancel* the "root" context, that signal is propagated through the whole tree of contexts derived from the root one.
Now each goroutine which were given a context, should "listen" on it to be notified when that cancellation signal is sent, and once the goroutine notices that it might drop whatever it was busy doing and exit.

In terms of actual `context.Context` type that signal is called "done" — as in "we're done doing whatever that context is assotiated with", — and that's why the goroutine which wants to know it should stop doing its work listens on a special channel returned by the context's method called `Done`.

#### Back to your example

To make it work, you'd do something like:

```golang
func (s *Server) doWork(ctx context.Context) int {
    s.lock.Lock()
    defer s.lock.Unlock()

    r := rand.Intn(100)
    log.Printf("Going to nap for %d", r)
    select {
    case <- time.After(time.Duration(r) * time.Millisecond):
        return r
    case <- ctx.Done():
        return -1
    }
}

func (s *Server)  GetValueWithTimeout(ctx context.Context, maxTime time.Duration) int {
    d := time.Now().Add(maxTime)
    ctx, cancel := context.WithDeadline(ctx, d)
    defer cancel()

    return s.doWork(ctx)
}

func main() {
    const maxTime = 50 * time.Millisecond

    rand.Seed(time.Now().UTC().UnixNano())

    s := NewServer()
    for i :=0; i < 10; i++ {
        v := s.GetValueWithTimeout(context.Background(), maxTime)
        log.Print(v)
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/lCUMLRL6pMx)).

So what happens here?

The `GetValueWithTimeout` method accepts the maximum time it should take the `doWork` method to produce a value, calculates the deadline, derives a context which cancels itself once the deadline passes from the context passed to the method and calls `doWork` with the new context object.

The `doWork` method arms its own timer to go off after a random time interval and then *listens on both the context and the timer.*
This one is the critical point: the code which performs some unit of work which is supposed to be cancellable must check the context to become "done" *actively,* by itself.
So, in our toy example, either the `doWork`'s own timer fires first or the deadline of the generated context gets reached first; whatever happens first, makes the `select` statement unblock and proceed.

Note that if your "do the work" code wold be more involved — it would actually do something instead of sleeping, — you would most probably need to check on the context's status periodically, usually after performing invividual bits of that work.

Comment: thank you very much for answering in a very sharp explanation. it makes sense to me. I also evaluate the second option where doWork returns a channel. i.e buffered channel and when it finishes it close a channel.   In my case narrow down to small examples but the idea if doWork wait on mutex API return no result,  so it tries to get value and if you can't don't block.  Go has very rich semantics for concurrency ;)